# Why won't my database reset using django_extensions, postgres, and psycopg2?

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2, django-extensions

I am using django-extensions `reset_db` command and get the following error:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: database "database_name" already exists
```

I've verified that my user has CreateDB and Login privileges. All packages are up to date. How can I tell why it's not able to reset the database correctly?

Comment: Did you try running the command with `./manage.py reset_db --verbosity=3`. Maybe it includes some more helpful output. Also the [`--traceback`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---traceback) option might show a little bit more of the context where it fails.

Comment: Just tried and neither do anything. Those settings flags are I believe for the django admin, not django-extensions, which is its own package and controls the `reset_db` command: https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions

Comment: Looking into the command I think it could be the problem that when dropping the database fails this gets only logged but the command does not actually raise or exit, so the script continues ([see this `try` block](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/django_extensions/management/commands/reset_db.py#L149)). If you have logging setup, could you check your logs for the traceback? If not, you could just edit the script while debugging to see if dropping the db works or has an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turned out my user was not the owner of the database - the postgres superuser was.

I changed the owner of the database to my Django user and the `reset_db` command worked:

`ALTER DATABASE database_name OWNER TO owner_name;`